# LM317T Hookup with 2K trimmer

Tags: voltage-regulator, potentiometer, lm317

I tried several times but without success to get the trimmer changing the output voltage of the LM317T . I tired to link the Pin 1 and 2  then all goes to ADJ pin of the LM317T and pin 3 to ground or 2 and 3 to ADJ and pin 1 to ground or using only 2 pins as shown below but nothing worked . Nothing wokred means the voltage remains constant .

Note that the trimmer is working fine when it is not combined with the voltage regulator ( 1 to + , 2 to Vout, 3 to - )
Could you advise which pins numbers to use and how?

[image]

Last update :

The input voltage is 5V of an arduino uno . The output voltage required is 3.6 V

[image]

Comment: The LM317 is in the   www.badbeetles.com website .I would check disipation in the pot ,Adress bypass caps and use 120R instead of 240R.

Comment: I used a 200R and the regulator seems to be working but with some unprecision (due to no capacitors were used until now) . I dont see the necessity for checking the dissipation because it is 5V input .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have any of the datasheet-recommended capacitors in your circuit. I bet your 317 isn't regulating.

Also, what's your input voltage?

And are you really connecting a [20K resistor](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=resistor+red+black+black+red+brown+) between ADJ and out? That can't possibly draw enough current to regulate (min guaranteed for regulation is 10mA). I suspect you've [read the resistor backwards](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=resistor+brown+red+black+black+red) and you think it's 120 ohm, but it's probably not (2% precision resistors are rather uncommon, whereas the blue-bodies ones usually are 1% metal-film). Best measure it to be certain.

Comment: Input voltage is 5 volt . Thank you for explanation about the relationship between the LM317, the current and the resitor . However i do not understand the necessety of the capacitor unless for makind stable the voltage and that is now what i am experiencing in the measures . I will add capacitors to see if it makes diffrence .

Comment: LM317 needs to drop about 3V, so with 5V input you cannot expect more than 2V regulated output.

Comment: And since minimum output is going to be 1.25V... that doesn't give you much range.

Comment: Thank you again for the information about the voltage drop . But somehow i am getting 3.74 volts  . I used 200R do you know how wast it possible to get such voltage  knowing the pot drop?

Comment: Yes, but it will probably vary with the load. That's the definition of it not being regulated. For 3.6V output (from 5V), look at an LDO (low dropout regulator) or a switching (buck) regulator. Alas 3.6V is not a very standard voltage (you can find 3.3V-output regs easily though), so you'll have to use an adjustable one.

Comment: Actually LT has some 3.6V LDOs, e.g. http://www.linear.com/product/LT1086 A bunch more can be found using parametric search on various distrubutor's sites, e.g. http://www.newark.com/ldo-fixed-voltage-regulators/output-voltage-nom/3-6v/pg/811353651

Comment: And [digikey has more](http://bit.ly/1lbKBvz) (including the LT one) although their catalog tends to be more repetitive as they list every single packaging form (reel etc.) as a separate product, so it's not that easy to see at a glance what your options are.

Comment: Ok all is clear now . I will first add some capacitors (470uF ) to see if i can get some stable voltage . The goal is to have DHT22 and ESP88 all working perfectly .

Answer (score 1):

Based on your picture I think you put 20K ohm resistor between Vout and ADJ pin change it to 240 ohm and it would be better to connect pin 1 and 2 of your trimmer together (and connect to ADJ) and pin 3 of it to ground

Comment: yes you are right, i did as you said . It seems to work but not so precisely .

Comment: You should put capacitor same as datasheet and Vin-Vout should be more than 3 volt